# Access of undefined property for AS3 generated movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, function, actionscript, instance

I have created movieclips on my timeline from actionscript... yet whenever I try to reference them, it says:

> Symbol 'puzzle1', Layer 'AS3', Frame 1, Line 27   1120: Access of
>   undefined property piece1.

But it's there. I can see it, and I can see where I gave it the instance name. Do I need to call instance names another way if they're not physically on the stage in my FLA when I publish it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content of the error I can assume that you're trying to access `piece1` which is on the stage from `puzzle1` which is also on the stage.

If this is the case, `piece1` will need to be referenced via:

```
MovieClip(root).piece1
```